# Inconsistent loading BitmapImage

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I've got my test program, and production program. I developed the test program first.
I'm loading a BitmapImage from a stream.
When I display the image in my test program it displays perfectly. In my production program, there's some graininess.

I've tracked the problem down to the BitmapImage itself.
The image width and height vary every so slightly between the two programs

eg Width is 816.001586914063 vs 816.001618655555.

I've compared the other image properties and these are the ones that differ

DpiX 199.99960327148438 vs 199.99960327148437 (last digit only)

DpiY as DpiX

Height 1056.0020947307178 vs 1056.0020751953125

Size

Width 816.00161865555458 vs 816.0015869140625

If I save the stream that I assign to the image.StreamSource before I initialize the image, and do a binary file compare - fc says they are identical.

My image init code looks like this:

```
   BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
   image.BeginInit();
   image.StreamSource = ms;
   image.EndInit();
```

Any suggestions much appreciated

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

The difference was that one program was set to "prefer 32-bit" and the other wasn't